# PHPExcel generated excel file not auto-calculating formula

Tags: excel, office365, phpexcel

**Issue**

Our web application generates Excel spreadsheets using the PHPExcel library. 
Normally we are able to open the Excel file, select 'Enable Editing' and then it auto calculates the formulas on the sheet. However this month (April 2018), I've been getting reports that the sheet no longer calculates automatically.

I need to find a solution on how to get these sheets to automatically calculate again upon opening the file.

**Solutions i've tried**

I've checked the settings under Formulas > Calculation Options, its always set to 'Automatic'.

**Manual Solutions**

I can force the sheet to calculate by either clicking into each cell with the formula and hitting Enter, or using CTRL ALT F9.

**Additional Notes**

1. Users are using Office 365 Excel.
2. The issue doesn't appear in LibreOffice Calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it will not be a solution, it may be improved to some extent by recalculating on the server side.

```
$writer     = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, self::EXCEL_TYPE);
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas();
$writer->save($tempfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there code running in the backend that disables auto calculation?
Try adding this VBA script:

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

This will force autocalculation when the workbook is opened.